# AES-256-CMC не шифрует

Tags: php, html, шифрование

Не шифруется кусок html файла с картинкой (base64). Если без картинки, то кусок html шифруется. Помогите исправить проблему! Стоит ли переходить на другие методы шифрования? Или я что-то делаю не так?

Пример:

```html
<body><p><s>TEST</s></p><h1><s>TEST</s></h1><h1><span style="color: rgb(230, 0, 0);">TEST</span></h1><p><img class="rg_ic rg_i" id="aySZcgmaOg7AwM:" jsaction="load:str.tbn" alt="Картинки по запросу boom" style="width: 300px; height: 168px; margin-left: -31px; margin-right: -30px; margin-top: 0px;" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBDENo6PDZhcH5UCRCPmHr/sPhyeNs1ol7IBJozAwbohRuGp20qlaElRg5l8nrETH9IgnmAUwapzWMByxLM2liSUdh6zVVCovzHBP/8dU0ivY/OIlJdqE64OwcyZB0sC base64...
```

Текста ошибки нет. Код я использую и в других местах, поэтому со стороны кода шифрования никаких проблем возникнуть не должно, но всё же:

```
public function encrypt($message, $hash){

    return openssl_encrypt($message, "AES-256-CBC", $hash, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, "fYkj34FShjf7Smo9");

}

public function decrypt($message, $hash){

    return openssl_decrypt($message, "AES-256-CBC", $hash, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, "fYkj34FShjf7Smo9");

}
```

Comment: Вы даже не показали, что конкретно вы делаете-то, так что мы не знаем, так или не так

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, код, которым вы шифруете. Какой вы получаете результат (текст ошибки, либо иной результат).